# applescript does not run from terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, applescript

why doesn't my applescript run from terminal  I can run it successfully from the editor

I run command

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e my_script.scpt
```

I get error

0:12: syntax error: A unknown token can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)

my script

```
set volume 2
set x to 0
open location "spotify:user:wunspe:playlist:meininki"
tell application "Spotify"
    set the sound volume to 0
    play
    repeat 10 times
        if sound volume is less than 70 then
            set sound volume to (sound volume + 10)
            set x to (x + 9)
            set volume output volume x without output muted --100%

            delay 3
        end if
    end repeat



end tell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a compiled script (file) you have to omit the `-e` flag and pass the full path to the script

```
/usr/bin/osascript /Users/myUser/path/to/my_script.scpt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
osascript -e "set Volume 10"
```

after the `-e` is the full content of the script.

if you put into some file (lets call it `volume.scpt`)

```
set Volume 10
```

you can call the script-file as

```
osascript /path/to/volume.scpt
```